# Runnable jar in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jar, aws-lambda, runnable

I have a requirement to run a runnable jar from AWS lambda. One option is to create a docker and use ECS to achieve the desired result. 
I am looking for an alternative approach using EC2. Is it possible to deploy a runnable jar in EC2 and then invoke it from AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible using EC2 Run Commands. You could use your favorite AWS SDK flavor (Java, Python, etc) to run a command on your EC2 instance from your Lambda function. Here's a good tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html

Comment: Thanks for that. I have one question on this. If I am calling a java jar using this run command, will this have the constraints as that if a lambda, i.e. 300 seconds? Basically, will this running jar be considered as part of the running lambda?

Comment: No I don't think so, as the Lambda invocation will only trigger your Run Command and end immediately. The Run Command will continue even though your Lambda has ended.

Comment: As a side note, there is a size limitation (50MB or something) so be careful with java :)